# How to get back result of a function after it is resolved, in an angularjs factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want go get back fingerprint of browser, I have created controller and a factory which should returns a the fingerprint result. Result is printed in the console but not getting in controller. I am new to javascript/ angular.
Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/amitabh300/pen/WwzMGV)

```
  angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
  .factory("DeviceInfo", function() {
    var getFP = function() {

        return new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components) {
          console.log("Fingerprint2 result " + result);
          return result;
        });

      }

    return {
      getFP: getFP,
    }
  })
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, DeviceInfo) {

    $scope.name = "Amitabh"
    $scope.fp = DeviceInfo.getFP();
  })
```

Comment: You have to convert DeviceInfo to Service with Promise initialisation. So MyCtrl will wait until DeviceInfo is ready.

Comment: Use $broadcast event for this.

Comment: can you please edit the codepen else can you give some code sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you don't know yet about promise, it's the angular way to deal with asynchronous result.

To be short, factory that return a result from asynchronous code return a promise.
A promise is an object that have a then method that take two callback, the first for success the second for failure.

This is a example of how you could make your code use promise:

```
  angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
  .factory("DeviceInfo", function($q) {
    var getFP = function() {    
        return $q(function(resolve) {
          new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components) {
            console.log("Fingerprint2 result " + result);
            resolve(result);
          });
        });
      }

    return {
      getFP: getFP,
    }
  })
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, DeviceInfo) {

    $scope.name = "Amitabh"
    DeviceInfo.getFP().then(function(fp) {
      $scope.fp = fp
    });
  })
```

Note that I know nothing about `Fingerprint2` maybe there is a better way to do. But I just want to give you a basic example of how to use promise.

I will recommend you reading about promise [kriskowal/q README](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) is a good start in my opinion. Than you can read [angular documentation about promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: first of all thanks for the answer, I have tried promise before this, but everytime it gives this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined. I have tried your code its giving same error. http://codepen.io/amitabh300/pen/ONvzpz

Comment: Which version of angular are you using ?

Comment: I am using Ionic 1.7.14
, which comes with angularjs

Comment: Type angular.version in you browser js console please.

Comment: {full: "1.4.3", major: 1, minor: 4, dot: 3, codeName: "foam-acceleration"}

Comment: On you code pen I got 1.5.3 which is beta, but I found a way to make it work I am going to edit my answer

Comment: Wow! thanks man,you saved my day, the code is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
  .factory("DeviceInfo", function($rootScope) {
      var getFP = function() {

        return new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components) {
            console.log("Fingerprint2 result " + result);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('fingerprintReceived', {
                'result': result})
            });
            //return result;
        }

        return {
          getFP: getFP,
        }
      })
    .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, DeviceInfo) {

        $scope.name = "Amitabh"
        $scope.fp = DeviceInfo.getFP();
        $scope.$on('fingerprintReceived', function(event, data){
          console.log(data.result)
          $scope.fp = data.result
       })
  })
```